# Django model save() - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my `models.py` I want to extend the Django User model by adding an email_list.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class User(AbstractUser):
    email_list = ArrayField(models.EmailField(max_length=100), null=True, blank=True)
    [...]
```

This email_list has to have the user email as default value. I found that the best way to do this, is by overriding the `save()` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.email_list.append(self.email)
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, when I add a user I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

And the `print(type(self.email_list))`, returns `<type 'NoneType'>`

What is wrong with the `ArrayField`?

Comment: Try to set `default` field kwarg to `[]`, currently you have `None` as its initial value.

Comment: @backatrouble you should use `list`, not `[]`. See the [warning in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a callabe such as list for the default value.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class User(AbstractUser):
    email_list = ArrayField(models.EmailField(max_length=100), null=True, blank=True, default=list)
    [...]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Answer (score 0):

the initial None value is occurring because null=True, even if default=list.
to avoid default value overriding, remove or set null to False

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class User(AbstractUser):
    email_list = ArrayField(models.EmailField(max_length=100), blank=True, default=list)
[...]
```